# jQuery Mobile application to load an external page and run js script when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, jquery-mobile

I want my jQuery Mobile application to load an external page when a button is clicked, but i am not sure of which event to use.

```
<a href="html/rarely_Used_Page.html" id="my_page" 
    data-role="button" data-inline="true" 
    data-theme="c"  data-icon="search" data-transition="none">
        List Members
</a>
```

### Source for rarely_Used_Page.html:

```
<div data-role="page"  id="some_id">

This is my rarely used page.
It is rarely used, so I don't want to include \
it in the main index.html page

</div>


// on load of rarely_Used_Page.html,  
// a script would run to perform a specific 
// task, but only for this page

<script>

$('[data-role=page #some_id]').live('pageshow', function () {
    alert("!");
    });
</script>
```

** edit ** 
Revised script. I am getting closer to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the jquery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) function.

```
$(document).load(function() {
     //code to perform tasks goes here
});
```

You can just put this at the bottom of rarely_Used_Page.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ajax, which you will be unless you explicitly ask not to, then only scripts inside the page div will fire when you load the page.  So, I can see two options

Put a script inside the page div

```
<script>alert("!");</script>
```

Include the following in a script which loads with the main document

```
$("#some_id").live("pageshow", function() { alert("!"); });
```

The first option will run the code before the page shows, the second will run it after.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't the piece of code which you've written there work? The a href="x.html" is the standard way to switch to an external page.